# Duvida em como monta uma consulta no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```sql
SELECT 
  `tab_banco`.`nome` AS `bancoNome`,
  `conta_bancaria`.`conta_apelido` AS `contaApelido`,
  `conta_bancaria`.`id` AS `idConta`,
  `movimento`.`conta_bancaria_id` AS `conta_bancaria_id`,
  `tabehist`.`HIST_Codigo` AS `codigoHistorico`,
  `tabehist`.`HIST_Descricao` AS `descricaoHistorico`,
  YEAR(`movimento`.`data_lancamento`) AS `ano`,
  SUM(
    (
      CASE
        WHEN (
          (
            `movimento_historico`.`historico_id` <= 499
          ) 
          AND (
            (`movimento`.`pendente` = 0) + (`movimento`.`pendente` = 1)
          ) 
          AND (
            `movimento_historico`.`historico_id` = `tabehist`.`HIST_Codigo`
          ) 
          AND (
            MONTH(`movimento`.`data_lancamento`) = 1
          ) 
          AND (
            YEAR(`movimento`.`data_lancamento`) = 2018
          )
        ) 
        THEN `movimento_historico`.`valor` 
        ELSE 0 
      END
    )
  ) AS `debitos1` 

  FROM ((((`conta_bancaria`
      JOIN `tab_banco`
        ON ((`conta_bancaria`.`tab_banco_id` = `tab_banco`.`id`)))
     JOIN `movimento`
       ON ((`conta_bancaria`.`id` = `movimento`.`conta_bancaria_id`)))
    JOIN `movimento_historico`
      ON ((`movimento`.`id` = `movimento_historico`.`movimento_id`)))
   LEFT JOIN `tabehist`
     ON ((`movimento_historico`.`historico_id` = `tabehist`.`HIST_Codigo`)))
WHERE (`movimento`.`visivel` = 1)
GROUP BY `movimento`.`conta_bancaria_id`,`codigoHistorico`
```

A consulta acima monta um relatório de dados, mas tem um porém eu não estou conseguindo deixar os valores dos anos separado, os mesmos estão se misturando, hoje eu setei o ano de 2018 da seguinte forma:
      ... `AND (YEAR(movimento.data_lancamento) = 2018 )`
mas quero deixar dinâmico para poder separar esses anos.

Answer (score 0):

Esses filtro que você utilizou no case, coloca ele na clausula `Where` na parte de baixo, e no case você filtra apenas os anos.

Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN(YEAR(DATA)) = 2017 THEN SUM(VALOR) ELSE 0 END) AS [2017],
       SUM(CASE WHEN(YEAR(DATA)) = 2018 THEN SUM(VALOR) ELSE 0 END) AS [2018]
       FROM conta_bancaria
       WHERE 'FILTROS' AND YEAR(DATA) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```